# TABINDEX not working on HyperLinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, tabindex

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="SignIn" runat="server" CssClass="SignIn" TabIndex="3">Sign In</asp:HyperLink>
```

the problem with the above is that TABINDEX does not work. I have also a username and password TEXTBOXES and the tabindex works with them, but the hyperlink does not work.

i need it also on other links, so replacing a sign in with a button is not helping me much, unless i replace all links with a button.

how to figure out why the hyperlink's tabindex is not working?

thnx

Comment: What else is on the form?  Tab index is fully supported with asp:HyperLinks, so maybe you are declaring duplicate tab indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out what it was :( after much trouble...

in my css i used:

```
outline: none;
```

so probably it WAS getting the focus, but it was just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the NavigateUrl of your hyperlink. If it is not set the hyperlink cannot get focus and tabindex will not work.

Comment: Perhaps pasting the generated output in its simplest form (strip any viewstate and irrelevant markup) would help.

Comment: not sure what info is relevant, but posted some in the question! need more?